# Installing kubernetes on Ubuntu 16.04 and 19.10 kills network connectivity

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kubernetes

Following [these steps](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-deploy-a-kubernetes-cluster-with-ubuntu-server-18-04/) to install kubernetes on Ubuntu 19.10 running in VMWare player with bridged networking. Installing kubernetes destroys the network connectivity of my guest OS. Specifically it is this command that kills my network connectivity:

`sudo apt-get install kubeadm kubelet kubectl -y`

In order to get my network connectivity back I had to remove the three packages and then delete two network interfaces:

`sudo ip link del flannel.1
sudo ip link del cni0`

I don't know why flannel was there because I hadn't installed it yet. Maybe it was leftover from a previous attempt where I did install flannel and the delete failed.

I noticed the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 running natively, so this probably isn't a VMWare Player issue. I was able to install kubeadm, kubelet, and kubectl on Ubuntu 18.04 running natively with no problems. I need another node though.

Kubernetes is supposed to run on Ubuntu 16.04+. Are the installation steps different for 16.04 and 19.10? It seems strange that it kills my networking.

Comment: I've verified the same failure on another Ubuntu 18.04 system running as the host OS.

Comment: What do you mean by "kills network connectivity"?

Comment: The host can't connect to anything else and nothing can connect to the host.